apply str() function to all columns in a pandas dataframe
I want to extract some characters from every cell in every column of a pandas dataframe. MWE below:
import pandas as pd

# initialize list of lists
data = [['tom', 'jerry'], ['nick', 'fury'], ['juli', 'anna']]
 
# Create the pandas DataFrame    
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Name', 'Name2'])

df2 = df['Name'].str[:1] # this works for a single column
df3 = df.map(str[:1]) # this does not work for the entire dataframe

`
I was able to remove the strings from a single column (df2) but couldn't do it for the entire dataframe (df3 attempt). The error I am getting is TypeError: type 'str' is not subscriptable

The argument to map() should be a function, not an expression.

lambda x: str(x)[:1]

There's no need to use the str() function, since the values are already strings. lambda x: x[:1]

The difference is that map works per element, not per column

You can use: pd.DataFrame({col:df[col].str[:1] for col in df.columns}). This can be assigned to a new dataframe.

You have to apply with a callable:
df.apply(lambda s: s.str[:1])

Or with a named function (the function must take a Series as input):
def first_letter(s):
    return s.str[:1]

df.apply(first_letter)

Output:
  Name Name2
0    t     j
1    n     f
2    j     a

If you use map (previously called applymap), this will apply the function per item, therefore you can't use .str and must go with pure python:
df.map(lambda x: str(x)[:1])

One drawback is that map can fail where apply+.str would replace invalid values with NaN.
For instance, getting the 4th character of each string:
# this will replace invalid outputs by NaN
df.apply(lambda s: s.str[3])

  Name Name2
0  NaN     r
1    k     y
2    i     a

# this will raise an Exception
df.map(lambda x: str(x)[3])

IndexError: string index out of range


map would also probably be less performant, requiring one  interpreter-level function call per item.
